# Relative Path Error When Migrating From Eclipse (PyDev) into VS Code

Tags: python, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I am completely new to the VS Code - find it very easy to use compared with Eclipse so I am trying to migrate our existing projects from Eclipse into VS Code.

By selecting the folder as the eclipse file, the interpolator seems to be selected automatically. But I do see the error as below.

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Development\\log\\Hedger.log'
  File "C:\Development\Optimizer\src\globals\config.py", line 17, in <module>
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler('../log/Hedger.log') # write log messages to log file
  File "C:\Development\Optimizer\src\run_server.py", line 1, in <module>
    import globals.config as config
```

Though the actual path should be "C:\Development\Optimizer\log\Hedger.

Could anyone give a guess/hint? Appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEhC6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

One: change the "../log/Hedger.log" to "./log/Hedger.log".

Two: in launch.json file setting '"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",' in "configurations".

Explains:

[${cwd} - the task runner's current working directory on startup](http://$%7Bcwd%7D%20-%20the%20task%20runner%27s%20current%20working%20directory%20on%20startup).
The default setting of 'cwd' is the "${workspaceFolder}", in your project means "C:\Development\Optimizer". So, the '../log/Hedger.log' means 'C:\Development\log\Hedger.log'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solution 2 works. It’s really shocking for me that the same code needs will run differently in different IDEs. But when I copy the source codes to the production environment and launch via a batch file, it seems to know the startup Folder is /src. So I was really shocked that VScode didn’t have that by default! Anyway good lesson learnt!